# os.system doesn't work until getting input in python

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I am trying to run  a youtube-dl command but when os.system(command) run, it is waiting an input on terminal(there is no input required). I press enter 2-3 time  than it  starts downloading.

```
url = sys.argv[1]
command = "youtube-dl " + url
print("downloading...")
os.system(command)
print("test")
```

I can't see "test" output. command works on cmd properly. waiting or subprocess command not working.

[image: dont start properly]

Comment: You may wish to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/9374673) on the difference between `subprocess` and `system`.

Comment: try waiting instead of pressing enter

Comment: i tried to wait but it's waiting an input.

Comment: Redirect its stdin to come from `/dev/null`, and then it _can't_ wait for inputs.

Comment: (or, better, use `subprocess` and `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`; particularly important to use portable practices since you're on Windows).

Comment: ...using your current code has security bugs anyhow. If someone tells you to download a URL that contains `$(rm -rf ~)` (or its Windows-y equivalent if you're running a Windows-native interpreter), you'll have a very bad day. The extra control `subprocess` gives you isn't just useful in its own right, it also prevents Bad Things from happening.

Comment: you are right.thank you. it looks dangerous.how can i transfer parameter safely?"stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL; " it's work btw

Comment: `subprocess.run(["youtube-dl", url], stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)`

Comment: thank you charles. it worked. I added on topic.

Comment: ...since you consider those comments a solution, I'll add a community-wiki answer that incorporates them so the question can be properly marked solved.

Comment: youtube-dl is written in Python and you can [import it like any other module](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl) without going through `os`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `subprocess` instead of `os.system` will let you set `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL` so it *can't* read from stdin (without going to the TTY, which most programs don't). Also, passing a list and keeping the default `shell=False` avoids security issues where contents inside the URL could be treated by the shell as commands to run.

```
subprocess.run(["youtube-dl", url], stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Comment: Nice.  @CharlesDuffy or someone else...can you explain why this fixes the problem?  Is it that `you-tube.dl` really is pulling some kind of input, or will this happen with any command?  Is it the redirection of `stdin` that is the key point here vs the other differences between `system` and `subprocess.run`?  Either which way, if `you-tube.dl` doesn't prompt for input when run at the command line, why won't it just run with `os.system`?

Comment: @Steve, a fair number of programs try to "passively" look for input -- checking whether the user is typing anything and printing out status or whatnot if they do; that's enough to trigger a SIGTTIN when not foregrounded. Without knowing anything about youtube-dl in particular, I would guess it to be one of those.